# Pass from vertex shader to fragment shader

Tags: java, opengl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm trying to send some vectors from vertex shader to fragment shader:
ex:

```
vec3 N = (view*model*vNormal).xyz
```

and when trying to reach it in fragment shader:

```
Link errorERROR: Input of fragment shader 'N' not written by vertex shader
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass values between shader stages you must use so called *varyings*; the keywords are `varying` or `out` and `in` – there was a keyword change between GLSL 1.20 to 1.40 but the basic gist that you need special type qualifiers. See  http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Type_Qualifiers#Shader_stage_inputs_and_outputs for the details.

Comment: ofc in vector shader I use 
`out vec3 N`
and in fs `in vec3 N`    but it doesnt help

Comment: @mjanisz1: You said your code was `vec3 N = ...`. In this code, `N` is a *local* variable. You need to declare shader stage inputs/outputs *globally*.